# Serve static html page with nginx based on rails server response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have 2 html files in /var/files: host1.html and host2.html.
I want nginx serving any of them (as index file) depending on rails response, eg http://localhost - should render host1.html or host2.html.

This is Rails controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    response.headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = 'host1.html'
    head :ok
  end
end
```

And nginx config:

```
upstream app_server {
  server 0.0.0.0:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 8080 default;

  location /{
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
    internal;
    root /var/files/;
  }
}
```

This is not working.

If remove internal - request proxied to Rails, but no internal redirect occurs...

Also, i want to serve not only html files - any actually.

Please advice. 
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you pass your request ro rails. Also, `X-Accel-Redirect` header must start with slash (`/`)

Comment: it is proxied to 0.0.0.0:3000 - rails server runs here.

Comment: > must start with slash (/)
i tried both.

Comment: "it is proxied to 0.0.0.0:3000" — I don't see this in your config. Show real full config

Comment: @AlexeyTen updated, please look. Please take into account that i am nginx newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use something like this

nginx config:

```
upstream app_server {
  server 0.0.0.0:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 8080 default;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
  }

  location /internal/ {
    internal;
    alias /var/files/;
  }
}
```

Rails controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    response.headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/internal/host1.html'
    head :ok
  end
end
```

Here we define “virtual” folder `/internal/` that will serve static files. When Rails “redirects” to `/internal/host1.html` nginx will match it to `location /internal/`, replace `/internal/` with `/var/files/` (see [alias](http://nginx.org/r/alias) for details) and serve static file `/var/files/host1.html`. But if user points his browser to `/internal/host1.html` he will get 404 error due to `internal` directive.